# No remote client protocols are enabled and no remote protocol was specified in the connection string

Tags: .net, sql-server-2016, windows-server-2016

Here's my situation. There are three servers:

1. Windows Server 2016 (**Server-1**)
2. Windows Server 2016 (**Server-2**)
3. Windows Server 2016 with SQL Server 2016 (**Server-SQL**)

I have some C# code which connects to **Server-SQL** which is identical on both **Server-1** and **Server-2** with identical connection strings.

The connection string looks something like this:

```
Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Server=Server-SQL;Database=database;Uid=user;Pwd=password;Encrypt=yes
```

The new 2018 undeprecated OLE DB driver is installed on both **Server-1** and **Server-2**.

The registry keys that enable/disable encryption are set up the same on both servers. e.g.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Client
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Client
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client
```

When running the same C# code on **Server-1** and **Server-2**, **Server-1** connects to the database without issue but **Server-2** throws out the following error message:

> A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not
>   accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL
>   Server Books Online. SQL Server Network Interfaces: No remote client
>   protocols are enabled and no remote protocol was specified in the
>   connection string [xFFFFFFFF].

With the following stack trace:

```
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection wningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
   at Squealer.Squealer.TryToConnectToDatabase(DatabaseConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
   at Squealer.Squealer.Run(String[] args)
```

I don't see any rules in the firewalls on either **Server-1** or **Server-2** that would prevent network traffic to **Server-SQL**.

WireShark captures traffic between **Server-1** and **Server-SQL** like this:
[image: WireShark trace of SQL traffic]

WireShark does not capture any traffic at all between **Server-2** and **Server-SQL** when attempting to establish a SQL connection.

Network connectivity between **Server-2** and **Server-SQL** has been established as follows:
[image: nslookup and ping results]

The SQL Server is configured to allow TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2. When it is configured to connect with TLS 1.1 the connection is successful.

I have compiled the .net code with both .net 4.6.2 and 4.7.0. Both servers have up to .net 4.7.0 installed.

Testing a UDL file that has Provider=MSOLEDBSQL.1 actually connects on both Servers.

In spite of extensive googling I've not found any trace of this particular error message so I have very little else to go on here..

Am I looking for a registry key that someone has mangled? I'm out of ideas.

Any help or light shed on this situation will be **great-fully** received.

Thank you.